# Function to change colour for all variables with same value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I just have theoretical question. I have event calendar. Every cell of calendar has few variables (name,status,service, etc..). Is it possible to color (text, backround of cells, etc...) with same value automatically?

So if some variable (for example service, this can have up to 1000 of values) in one cell is == with variable in other cells, change text color for all of these values, where value is same.

[FOR EXAMPLE : if value is *tbc invoiced* change text color of this value (*tbc invoiced*) in all cells to green, if value is *open*, change text colour in all cells to blue, etc ... ]

Or I need to set for every value text colour?

And is there anything like dynamic colour range? So I don't need to put colours manually, but text will get colour automatically.

Does anybody get it, or I need to be a little more specific?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use classes to represent the variable values, then you can make the colors change automatically using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS classes/selectors to color your cells based on their values.